# How to write a conditional statement with a value but only if it's the only value?

Tags: php, arrays

```
if($uriarray['value'] == 0 ){
```

I have an input form which includes values. The values are in a checkbox. I want to show something if it's the only value, but not if it's included with other values. So if the value is 0 I want to show something but if it includes other values like 1,2,3 etc, I don't want to show it. Is this something that's possible?

If & only if?

Comment: can you paste the form html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your HTML form. For example, if you specify the names of the checkboxes in array-form like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="uriarray[]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="uriarray[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="uriarray[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="uriarray[]" value="3" />
```

you would receive an array in PHP with all checked values.

```
<?
  if (count($_POST['uriarray']) == 1) {
    $onlyValues = $_POST['uriarray'][0];
  }
?>
```

If you also want to check the single value to be 0:

```
<?
  if ((count($_POST['uriarray']) == 1) && ($_POST['uriarray'][0] == "0")) {
    //Do something
  }
?>
```

Comment: `<select name="value[]"><option value="0">Test1</option><option value="1">Test2</option>` I cant access the code right now but you get the idea

Comment: The <select> isn't used for checkboxes. You can use the multiple attribute to change the dropdown into a list in which you can use multiple options, but it's still a different interface compared to checkboxes.